# Call action method from view to automatically populate form value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form which is used to create a resource, and it has two fields to be populated. When a user enters a value into the first field, I want to automatically call back to an action method on the server which will determine the value to use in the second field, without the user having to submit the form.

For example:

- Full Name - User enters this value
- Username - View calls server with the value specified in Full Name, server calculates value to be used, server passes value back to view, view presents the value.

Is it possible to do this in MVC core, and if so, can you please point the right direction?

---

I've been reading up on remote validation, and feel that I could probably use (or abuse) it in order to achieve the functionality looking for, but I'd imagine there's a property way to do this.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@mj1313's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61358795/6236042) was extremely helpful, but I didnt like the idea of having some loose Javascript kicking around in my views, especially since I may need to use this same functionality in multiple views.

I ended up converting the script into a global function, and calling it from within the `onchange` event like so.

**JS Function**
(in `site.js`)

```
function fullNameToUserName (fullNameId, usernameId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get", // GET rather than POST
        url: "/User/GetUserNameFromFullName",
        data: {
            fullname: $(fullNameId).val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $(usernameId).val(result);
        }
    })
}
```

**Action method**

```
[HttpGet("GetUserNameFromFullName")] // GET rather than POST
public IActionResult GetUserNameFromFullName(string fullName)
{
    var username = fullName.Split(" ");

    return Ok(username.First());
}
```

**Model**

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApp.Models.UserModel

@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FullName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, new
{ 
    onchange = $"fullNameToUserName({@Html.IdFor(m => m.FullName)}, {@Html.IdFor(m => m.Username)});"
})

@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Username)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
```

The only problem I have with this approach is that the call to `fullNameToUserName(fullNameId, usernameId)` is not strongly-typed, and if this function is called from multiple views, it's likely to be miss-typed at some point.

While [@mj1313's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61358795/6236042) was great and pointed me in the right direction, I wasn't fully satisfied with the approach. Personally, I prefer this approach as it's slightly more reusable and keeps my view's more lean.

Answer (score 1):

Remote Validation can only do the validation without submitting the form, but It can't assign value to another field. In your case. It's actually very simple. You can use the js onchange event listen to the first field, in the event, use ajax to access the background. and then fill the returned value into the second field in the callback function. Below is a simple test

View:

```
<span>Full Name</span>
<input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName" />

<span>User Name</span>
<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" />

@section scripts{
<script>
    $("#FullName").on("change", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/User/GetUserName",
            data: {
                fullname: $("#FullName").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#UserName").val(result);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetUserName(string fullname)
{
    var username = fullname.Split(" ");

    return username.First();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I was really hoping this wouldnt be the solution - I was hoping to avoid writing Javascript and have it taken care of by C# attributes or tag helpers, but it doesnt seem like there's anything build in for this - unless you happen to know otherwise? Thanks nonetheless though, it's a working solution!